# Почему не обновляется стейт?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    TextInput,
    View,
    Button,
    StyleSheet,
    FlatList,
    Text
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
            items: [
            'XXX',
            'YYY',
            'lelel sdsdsd sdsd',
            ], 
            text: ''
    };
    this.pres=this.pres.bind(this);
}
  pres() {
    let message = this.state.text;
    this.state.items.push(message);
    this.setState({items: this.state.items});
  }      
  render() {
   return (
    <View>
            <View style={styles.box}>
                    <FlatList
                    data={this.state.items} 
                    renderItem={({item}) => <View style={styles.messageBlock}>
                                            <Text style={styles.message}>
                                                    {item}
                                            </Text>
                                            </View>}
                    />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.box}>
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    value={this.state.text}
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
                    />
                    <Button
                    title='Send'
                    onPress={this.pres}
                    />
            </View>
    </View>
  );
 }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    box: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            margin: 15
    },
    input: {
            flex: 1,
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 1
    },
    messageBlock: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            marginTop: 2
    },
    message: {
            fontSize: 20,
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 20,
            color: '#fff'
    }
});
```

Ввожу данные в инпут, беру оттуда валю и добавляю в конец массива items, а стейт не обновляется, подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя менять state не методом this.setState ([документаци](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly))

> The only place where you can assign this.state is the constructor.

Единственное место где можно присваиваить значение напрямую это конструктор.

```
pres() {
    this.setState({ 
      items: [...this.state.items, this.state.text],
      text: ''
     });
  }
```

[Рабочий пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/rmy2jlk1pq)

Также обрати внимание, что метод setState может быть асинхронным - [документация](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)